# Regex to find an ID (X.123) with and without double square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following to look for instances of an ID such as X.123:

```
$regex_id   = "/\b[Xx][\.][0-9]{1,4}\b/";
preg_match_all($regex_id, $html, $matches_id, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The matched IDs are converted to some stored text.  This part works well, however I need to add some functionality.  Now some ID's will be enclosed in double brackets, such as [[X.123]], and I need to match either the standalone ID, or the bracketed ID.

The standalone ID's will be replaced with some text (ex: `X.123 >> MyText`).
The bracketed ID's will be replaced with an image (ex: `[[X.123]] >> <img src='mypic.png'>`.

I need to be careful how this is done so I don't replace `[[X.123]]` with `[[MyText]]`. As Jason McCreary indicated below, I can simply order the two expressions though that's probably not the best way.

Is this the correct expression to match the bracketed ID?

```
\[\[[Xx][\.][\s][0-9]{1,4}\]\]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *naive* way would be to do two passes.

1. Replace `[[X.123]]`
2. Replace `X.123`

I would do so with a single call to [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) using arrays for the search/replace parameters.

**UPDATE**

A regular expression for `[[X.###]]` would be:

```
\[\[[Xx]\.\d{1,4}\]\]
```

Comment: I'd go with the first approach. I don't want to sacrifice readability for a single line.

Comment: I'm not advocating a *single line*. I'm advocating a *single call* to  `preg_replace` as it accepts *mixed* parameters.

Comment: Cleaned the expression up slightly:  `\[{2}[Xx]\.\d{1,4}\]{2}`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct expression to match the bracketed ID?
>
> \[\[[Xx][\.][\s][0-9]{1,4}\]\]

Unnecessary characters in there.

```
\[\[[Xx]\.[0-9]{1,4}\]\]
```

**EDIT**

...that will match the bracketed-only version.  If you need match both:

```
(?:\[\[)?[Xx]\.[0-9]{1,4}(?:\]\])?
```

...which won't create back-references to the brackets if/when they do match.  The one possible issue here is that you match brackets on one side or the other *but not both*.  LMK if you need it to be more stringent than that.

Cheers

Comment: I think he wants it to match on both bracketed and unbracketed.  This will only match on bracketed.

Comment: @David You may be right, didn't sound that way to me "*is this the correct expression to match the bracketed ID?*".  But updated just in case.

Comment: She needs it to match on both sides.. my users often throw me for a loop with entered text.  GIGO! :)

Comment: @Madbreaks I think this is the key statement from the question: "I need to match either the standalone ID, or the bracketed ID".

Comment: @Madbreaks -- somebody apparently downvoted your answer.  I upvoted shortly after you posted.  If I deselect my vote, your answer is shown "-1".  FYI.

Comment: I'll give you Answer for this to help make up for the bogus downvote.  You provided essentially the same answer as Jason.

Comment: @acoder NOT bogus at all.  Your question clearly says:  "I need to match _either_ the standalone ID, _or_ the bracketed ID".  When I looked at this solution, it only matched the bracketed and NOT the standalone.  If that's not what you meant, then you need to be more clear with your question.

Comment: Ok - fair enough.  Not sure I would have downvoted the answer, however you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @a coder, this only answers the regular expression part of your question. Not both. I'm not advocating my answer. However, you should award the answer to that which you feel best *answers* your question. Not the user you feel sorry for. That would be misleading to future readers.

Comment: Correct.  I've reselected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\[\[)?[Xx]\.[0-9]{1,4}(\]\])?
```

Comment: How can you ensure that the string has _both_ `[[` and `]]`?

Comment: @Wiseguy Yes, that's a risk.  Might be able to do it with a lookahead.